# Oracle. load data infile error

Tags: image, oracle, sql-loader

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE image_table (
   image_id   NUMBER(5),
   file_name  VARCHAR2(30),
   image_data BLOB);
```

**SQL:**

```
load data infile * replace into table test_image_table
fields terminated by ','
(
     image_id   INTEGER(5),
     file_name  CHAR(30),
     image_data LOBFILE (CONSTANT 'C:\img.txt') TERMINATED BY EOF
 )
```

**C:\img.txt:** 001,C:\1.jpg

**Error:**
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 1

What I do wrong ??

Comment: That's not valid SQL. Looks like a sqlldr control file (though I'm not sure your syntax is correct). Are you trying to run that in sqlplus?

Comment: `load data infile` is not a valid sqlldr control syntax either.

Comment: I do like in this example (http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ#How_does_one_use_SQL.2ALoader_to_load_images.2C_sound_clips_and_documents.3F)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `SQL*Loader` which is not `SQL*Plus`. You have to save what you call `SQL` as a file with the `.ctl` extension, and call sqlldr:

```
sqlldr login/password@database control=my_file.ctl
```

Note that `infile *` means that you must have some `BEGINDATA` inside your CTL file.

Comment: and how to call sqlldr? trying to do it through sql developer - Error Unknown Command. And I will need it later to call in zend framework. To download an image to a table

Comment: @Andrei: sqlldr is a console program.

Comment: @Andrei: No. You open a command line window, you `cd` to the directory where the ctl file lies and you type the command above.

Comment: then this method is not suitable. @Benoit may be tell me as upload images into the database without the use of the directory in Oracle? So many ways tried to and do not work (
I use Oracle + Zend Framework

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use the `SQL*Plus` to run your `SQL*Loader` control file. Use one of the below `sqlldr` in your UNIX command line. Don't forget to save your mentioned `SQL` file as a `.ctl` file.

```
sqlldr username@server/password control=loader.ctl
```

or

```
sqlldr username/password@server control=loader.ctl
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in SQL Developer: host sqlldr username/password control=my_file.ctl

Comment: [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your code